# Find a linearly dependent subset

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find a linearly dependent subset of R3 in which no two vectors are scalar multiples of each other, however I thought for a set to be linearly dependent at least two vectors had to be scalar multiples of each other? Or am I misunderstanding the definition of dependence?

Comment: If a set of two vectors are linearly dependent, they must be scalar multiples of each other. However, this need not be the case if you choose more than 2 elements to make your linearly dependent subset. In particular, I think you should focus on coming up with a subset of size 3. Suppose you choose two vectors, neither a scalar multiple of each other. What would a third vector need to be in order for the set of all three vectors to be linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes, you are. For a set $S$ to be linearly dependent, $S$ must be nonempty. If $|S|=1$, we must have $S=\{0\}$. If $|S|=2$, one of the vectors in $S$ is a scalar multiple of the other. If neither vector is zero, then in fact each is a scalar multiple of the other, this is the case you mentioned. But $S$ could have more than two elements, it could even be infinite.

Comment: To be linearly independent just means that one of the vectors in $S$ can be written as a linear combination of some of the other vectors in $S$. For instance, $\{(1,1),(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is linearly dependent, since $(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)$, but none of these vectors is a multiple of any of the others.

Comment: In fact, you couldn't arrange for the vectors _not_ to be scalar multiples of each other in only two dimensions.  In $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ , you need to contrive three vectors so that $ \ a \vec{u} \ + \ b \vec{v} \ + \ c \vec{w} \ = \vec{0} \ $ .  A geometric interpretation of this is that the three vectors $ \ a \vec{u} \ , \ b \vec{v} \ $ , and $ \ c \vec{w} \ $ can form a closed triangle (no two are parallel, but the three together are linearly dependent).  By extension, you could pick larger sets of vectors making closed irregular polygons (so that no two sides are parallel).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner What you say in your first sentence is not true. It is true if you replace "two" with "at most one", though.

Comment: Maybe I could have said that better: I meant that you could not arrange to have two linearly-dependent vectors in two-dimensional space be anything _other_ than scalar multiples.

Comment: @colormegone You can arrange vectors to not be scalar multiples of each other in only two dimensions. Just look at the example provided by @{Andrés E. Caicedo}. Indeed if you arrange 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that they are linearly independent, then they will lie in a subvectorspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Choose two vectors that are independent of one another plus a linear combination of the two to create a set of linear dependent vectors.  But, none will be scalar multiples of the others.

Comment: @colormegone Yes you cannot arrange two linearly-dependent vectors in $\mathbf{any}$ vector space so that not one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Answer (score -1):

To relate the issue of linear dependence to the dimension of the space we're working in, we can start with $ \ \mathbb{R}^2 \ $ , a two-dimensional plane.  There, the equation for linear dependence, $ \ a \vec{u} \ + \ b \vec{v} \ = \ 0 \ $ *unavoidably* leads to, say, $ \vec{v} \ = \ -\frac{a}{b} \vec{u} \ $ .  So one vector is a scalar multiple of the other and the "subspace" in which these vectors are found is one-dimensional.

On passing to $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ , we have other options.  We can still have vectors which are scalar multiples of one another, in which case they are again found in a one-dimensional subspace.  But we can now also have *two*-dimensional subspaces, in which we can arrange three *co-planar* vectors, no two of which are scalar multiples of one another (no two are parallel) , with $ \ a \vec{u} \ + \ b \vec{v} \ + \ c \vec{w} = \ 0 \ $ .  These would "look like" three vectors forming a closed triangle; we could even make sums of larger numbers of vectors to make *planar* irregular polygons (so that we still have no pairs of parallel sides).

A set of linearly *independent* vectors in $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ would neither be co-planar, nor form a closed path (the vector sum would not equal zero).  With three vectors, we can guarantee that "coplanarity" implies linear dependence (and *vice versa*).

Comment: It is also possible to find 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that any two of them are linearly independent (for example $v_1 = (1,0)$, $v_2=(0,1)$ and $v_3=(1,1)$). I don't understand why you bring the dimension of the surrounding space into this problem.